# Firebase photoURL from a Google auth provider returns a jpg with colors inverted

Tags: javascript, image, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

When I authenticate a user via Firebase (below), the resulting `user` contains a photoURL that has inverted colors. Click this jpg url to see the color inversion:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-JVpfmGGJuO8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAME/sMJVq9F8gec/photo.jpg

Yet when I paste that URL into Stack Overflow's "image" editor button, it shows the image not inverted below:

[image]

```
signIn() {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login');
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result: any) => {
      this.user = result.user;
    })
  }
```

What's going on? Do I need to decompress the image somehow?

Comment: Getting this now, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

For future adventurers to this page: This problem only exists for Alphabet employees. Query the internal search engine and you'll solve it.